# Getting a memory leak after calling lifecycle.addObserver

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-architecture-components, leakcanary

After adding a lifecycle observer from the Android jetpack arch component, I get the following leak. Any ideas?

````
LeakingInstance(referenceKey=3f842e15-cca3-465a-8345-3a241c8befca, referenceName=, instanceClassName=androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment, watchDurationMillis=561193, excludedLeak=false, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1
│    Leaking: NO (it's a GC root)
│    Anonymous subclass of com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub
│    ↓ InputMethodManager$1.this$0
│                           ~~~~~~
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mImeInsetsConsumer
│                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ImeInsetsSourceConsumer
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ImeInsetsSourceConsumer.mController
│                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.InsetsController
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ InsetsController.mViewRoot
│                       ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ViewRootImpl
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewRootImpl.mActivityConfigCallback
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.-$$Lambda$ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord$HOrG1qglSjSUHSjKBn2rXtX0gGg
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ -$$Lambda$ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord$HOrG1qglSjSUHSjKBn2rXtX0gGg.f$0
│                                                                                ~~~
├─ android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
│                                          ~~~~~~~~
├─ com.x.x.MainActivity
│    Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true)
│    ↓ MainActivity.mFragments
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController
│    Leaking: YES (MainActivity↑ is leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentController.mHost
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks
│    Leaking: YES (FragmentController↑ is leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl
│    Leaking: YES (FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks↑ is leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mPrimaryNav
╰→ androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
​     Leaking: YES (Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
, retainedHeapSize=null)```
````

Comment: show how you add the observer

Comment: did you found any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known IME leak in the Android framework on Q Beta. Should be identified as a known leak in the latest release: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-analyzer/src/main/java/leakcanary/AndroidKnownReference.kt#L312

Answer (score 0):

There are different states of lifecycler observer like  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) or  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME), You can remove the listener or receiver in onPause lifecycle method and then again intialize in onResume lifecycle method.

Please use below link to go through the details of lifecyler aware components and its lifecycle

[Lifecycler Observer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)